# Abstração de SQL com FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firedac

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com abstração de *SQL* num sistema multi bancos.
Por exemplo:
**Firebird**: `SELECT SUBSTRING(nome FROM 5 FOR 8) FROM clientes`
**Oracle**: `SELECT SUBSTR(nome,5,8) FROM clientes`
Como fazer para que o aplicativo, após identificar qual banco está sendo usado, prepare a instrução *SQL* corretamente?
Sei que existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Mas tecnicamente qual a melhor maneira de fazer ou a mais aconselhada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você usa 2 conexões diferentes com o mesmo componente de conexão, você pode usar o `Try`, segue exemplo:

```
try
  //Tenta efetuar a rotina pensando no Firebird
  SELECT SUBSTRING(nome FROM 5 FOR 8) FROM clientes
except
  //Deu erro no Firebird, então tenta no Oracle
  SELECT SUBSTR(nome,5,8) FROM clientes  
end;
```

E se você já consegue identificar qual o Banco conectado pode fazer sem medo:

```
if (Banco = Firebird) then
begin
  SELECT SUBSTRING(nome FROM 5 FOR 8) FROM clientes
end
else if (Banco = Oracle) then
begin
  SELECT SUBSTR(nome,5,8) FROM clientes
end;
```

As duas formas vão lhe satisfazer, mas EU uso a segunda forma, pois, da espaço para novas conexões! E ao meu ver, é a maneira correta!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas na minha busca pela melhor forma de se fazer isso, gostaria justamente de não precisar escrever o mesmo código duas vezes. Se for prezar por segurança, sua resposta considero a melhor, mas prezando por velocidade de desenvolvimento, aí fica complicado.  
Mas acho que por hora é o que dá para fazer.

Comment: Exatamente, como não existe um padrão entre os parâmetros da "Abstração" dos dois bancos mencionados não resta opção, temos que escrever novamente! Caso apareça uma nova alternativa eu edito a resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionado por "Junior Moreira", essa abordagem resolve e acredito que é ou foi bastante utilizada por muitos dev's, trabalhando com aplicações que usam multibanco.

No entanto Firedac tem uma opção interessante para auxiliar, chamada de MACRO.

Que você pode fazer esse mix ou como for melhor para você.

Veja um exemplo usado para **UpperCase**:

```
Select   {uCase(Nome)} from clientes     ///o FireDAC irá converter para UpperCase o nome do cliente;

Select   {LCase(Nome)} from clientes     ///o FireDAC irá converter para LowerCase o nome do cliente;
```

**Outro exemplo**

Abstração do dialeto SQL
Se o aplicativo precisar suportar vários DBMSs, ele deve estar ciente de que seus dialetos SQL podem ser diferentes. As sequências de fuga do FireDAC permitem que você escreva comandos SQL independentes do SQL.

Por exemplo, a função para converter string em maiúsculo é diferente no MySQL, Oracle e Microsoft SQL Server. Mas o seguinte comando funciona em qualquer DBMS:

```
SELECT {ucase(Name)} FROM MyTable
```

Observe que com o SQLite, você precisa adicionar o aparelho à sua cláusula de "usos". Em casos mais complexos, partes do comando ou mesmo o comando completo devem ser escritas de forma diferente. Em seguida, a sequência de fuga condicional do FireDAC ajuda: FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs

```
{IF Oracle} SELECT * FROM OracleTab {fi}
{IF MSSQL} SELECT * FROM MSSQLTab {fi}
```

Acredito que você irá "perder" um tempo para escrever as classes, mas valerá apena
e poderá usar em qualquer delphi usando Firedac.

Documentação completa em :
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)